# How to access Crash log on iPhone from the App?

Tags: ios, xcode, logging, crash

I want to implement an "Automatic Crash log reporting system" into my apps. So I want to test if any Crash log exists, then grab it, and mail it back to me.

Is there any way to find these files from an App?
Please.

As far as I can see Piictu, and Camera+ somehow managed to do something similar.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [PLCrashReporter](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/) framework with a neat wrapper class by amazingsyco called [CrashReporter](https://github.com/amazingsyco/CrashReporter) at GitHub.

Moreover, I made a friendly UI like the one below from [dribbble](http://dribbble.com/shots/268234-Crash-Reporter-UI-for-Moquu).

[image]

The workin' example merged in to [Moquu](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/moquu-photo-scratcher-for/id443397719) can be downloaded soon (the update will be submitted in the next few days) from the [AppStore](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/moquu-photo-scratcher-for/id443397719).
There's a hidden crash feature for testing purposes (hold three fingers for five seconds on about view).

Answer (score 1):

TestFlight released their [SDK](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/) yesterday. It has many awesome features including automatic crash reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking in Organizer, then into devices > Device logs, and find your app? These update as far as I know everytime you plug your device in.
Youll probably know of this already, but you havent mentioned it so I posted just incase its what youre looking for.